# Why am I getting a MySQL and Peewee Traceback error

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm trying to pull from a MySQL database and collect the values in a string. I decided to start by just printing each row from the database but I keep getting the error below. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  ...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 163, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 321, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 505, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 724, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1069, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 676, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 223, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
peewee.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'")
```

Here is my code. I have removed the db credentials for obvious reasons.

```
import mysql.connector
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase(host="########", user="########", password="########", database="lukesmed_biblical")

print(db)

class Response(Model):
  PRIMARY = IntegerField()
  category = TextField()
  text = TextField()
  class Meta():
    database = db
    table_name = "responses"


db.connect()
for text in Response.select():
  print(text().text)
db.close()
```

Comment: Show us the **full** traceback! It is BTW an error traceback, not a traceback error. The real error type is in the last line of the output.

Comment: I just updated the question with the end of the error. I had to remove some of the middle of the traceback because it would not allow me to post but so much code. Here is a link to the full error on pastebin. https://pastebin.com/z6DEurjR

Comment: why do you use `()` in `text().text` ? As for me `for text in ... ` should gives you row from databases in `text` and you should use `text.text`, `text.category` It could be more readable if you use different name - like `item` or `row` - `for item in Response.select(): print(item.text)`

Comment: error shows `"Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'"` - do you have column `id` in your database?

Comment: No, I do not have an ```id``` column.